# What is the zipper?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, differential-topology, cobordism, topological-quantum-field-theory

**1. Defining an "open-closed TFT"**
Consider the following category of open-closed cobordisms $Cob_2^{o/c}$:

- Objects are compact oriented smooth one-dimensional manifolds possibly with boundary (i.e. diffeomorphic to disjoint unions of oriented circles and oriented intervals.)
- Morphisms are equivalence classes of bordisms. Here, a bordism $B:M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth oriented two dimensional manifold $B$ together with an orientation preserving smooth (not necessarily surjective) map $\phi_B: \overline M \coprod N \rightarrow \partial B$ that is a diffeomorphism to its image.

One can define an equivalence class on these bordisms, a composition of morphisms, a monoidal structure and so on to make $Cob_2^{o/c}$ into a monoidal category.

> An *open-closed TFT* is defined as
> a symmetric monoidal functor
> $$Z: Cob_2^{o/c} \rightarrow vect(\mathbb k).$$

Let us now look at the (oriented) circle $S^1$ and the (oriented) interval $[0,1]$. We consider the vector spaces $Z(S^1)$ and $Z([0,1]).$

**2. Question**
My lecture notes state the following:

> The zipper gives a linear map $i_*: Z(S^1) \rightarrow Z([0,1]).$

- How is *the zipper* defined? I suppose it is a bordism $S^1 \rightarrow [0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd ask whoever wrote those lecture notes; it's a bit remiss of them not to include a picture or something.

Here's my guess, this feels like the most "obvious" cobordism $S^1 \to [0, 1]$: start with a cylinder (the identity cobordism $S^1 \to S^1$) and pinch one end shut. (So it's kinda like a zipped-up purse, I guess.)

Comment: This is the bordism I too would have guessed. I'll ask my prof, thanks anyway.